# How to correctly get rid of CORS error when trying to fetch from external URL (e.g. S3 bucket) in Angular?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, cors, http-headers, fetch-api

I'm getting a list of objects from an api that connects to AWS. These objects contain a property that is a pre-signed url that could then be used to download an image, for example.

I'm using these urls to then have a button that when you click it, it downloads the file.

When I tried to `fetch(presignedUrl)` I've got:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/S3_DIR/IMAGE_1.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&Expires=6548462946&Signature=BBASKH234DFFVSFVFV' from origin 'https://myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

At first, I thought this was an issue with the S3 Bucket CORS policy configuration But the CORS policy was configured correctly:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I'm certain that this issue has to do with Angular. To test this hypothesis I made a simple HTML file with a script that when the button is clicked it downloads every file in the array of objects obtained from S3. I copy-pasted the array obtained from S3.

```js
const files = [
{
    "url": "https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/S3_DIR/IMAGE_1.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&Expires=6548462946&Signature=BBASKH234DFFVSFVFV",
    "name": "image_1.jpeg",
    "size": 101943
},
{
    "url": "https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/S3_DIR/IMAGE_1.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&Expires=6548462946&Signature=BBASKH234DFFVSFVFV",
    "name": "image_2.jpeg",
    "size": 101943
},
];

function toDataURL(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
}

async function download(url, name) {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = await toDataURL(url);
  a.download = name;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}

function downloadAll() {
  files.forEach((file) => {
    download(file.url, file.name);
  });
}
let btn = document.getElementById("download-btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", downloadAll);
```

This worked as intended. Then I tried the same but with a new fresh angular app created with `ng new my-app`,  and it didn't work. So, I conclude that this issue has to do with Angular

I also did some experiments with the `environment.ts` file, but sometimes work, and sometimes I get the same CORS error I mentioned above:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  s3BucketName: 'https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com',
};
```

Comment: any solution yet?